# Multiple Android deep link, app goes in onResume()

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an html page with two links as follow:

```
<a href="myApp:sometext1;scheme=myApp">Test 1</a>
```

`<a href="myApp:sometext2;scheme=myApp">Test 2</a>`

I open it with android Internet app. In my "Hello word" manifest application i declare:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="testapp">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="myApp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I can open my application with both links.The first time i click on both links my app starts and passes through  onCreate (my app was not in background before click). The second time (app now is in recent tasks), the first link clicked before in chronologically order pass through onResume only  but the second pass on onCreate. This will be the behaviour if i try open links n times until i kill application from recent. Any ideas?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Android activity, by default can be instantiated multiple times. You should use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to override this behavior. There are some other flags that might interest you if you - [here is the link to documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: I will try as soon as possible, but what i was expected was one instance every time i click a link so every time OnCreate, not that the first i clicked after the first click goes always in onResume and the other alway OnCreate. All in OnCreate or all in OnResume for the same link

Comment: In my real application i put `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in 2 activities involved in the process related to deep link. It seems to work.